# How to change the anchor point from the top-left corner of a transformation matrix to the bottom-left corner?

Tags: objective-c, css, matrix, transform, cgaffinetransform

Say, I have an image on an HTML page.
I apply an affine transformation to the image using CSS3 matrix function.
It looks like:

```
img#myimage {
    transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty);
    /* use -webkit-transform, -moz-transform etc. */
}
```

The origin of an HTML page is the top-left corner and the y-axis is inverted.

I'm trying to put the same image in an environment (cocos2d) where the origin is the bottom-left corner and the y-axis is upright.

To get the same result in the other environment, I need to transform the origin somehow and reflect that in the resulting `CGAffineTransform`.

It would be great if I can get some help with the matrix math that goes here. (I'm not so good with matrices.)

Answer (score 1):

The following formula would work,
for converting the position from CSS3 to Cocos2d:

(screen Size - "y" position in CSS3 - height of object)

Explanation:

1. To make the origin for the Cocos environment same as for the CSS3 environment we would only have to add the screen size to the cocos2d's bodies y co-ordinate. 
   Eg. The screen size is (100,100) and the body is a point object if you place it at (0,0) in CSS3 it would be at the top left corner. If we add the screen size to the y co-ordinates for cocos2d the object would be placed at (0,100) which is the top-left corner for cocos2d as well
2. To make the co-ordinates same, since the Y axis is inverted, we have to subtract the "Y" co-ordinate given in CSS3 from the Screen Size for Cocos2d. Suppose we place the same point object in the previous example at (0,10) in CSS3 we would place it at (0, 100 - 10) in cocos2d which would be the same positions on the screen
3. Since our body would NOT always be a point object we have to take care of its anchor point as well. If suppose the body's height is 20 and we place it at (0,10) in CSS3 then it would be placed at the top-left position and would be coming down because the Y axis is inverted
   Hence we would also have to subtract the body's total height from the screen size and "y" co-ordinate to place it at the same position which would be (0, 100 - 10 - 20) putting the body at the same place in cocos2d environment

I hope I am correct and clear :)